# Screen keeps dimming no matter what I set in power options

Tags: release-freya, display, power

My screen is dimming and then completely black afters some inactivity period - but in power settings I've got "Dim screen when inactive" switched off. Is there any setting I am missing ?

Freya 0.3.2

Comment: Have you checked that it's both for "battery" and "plugged-in" states?

Comment: And also the "Turn off screen when in active after " setting set to "Never" (for both Plugged in and On Battery?

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf-editor, and open up `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power`

And there you can find various useful power-related settings that you can tweak/toggle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you for all your help, I'm really impressed by the response.

I did try all mentioned solutions but what helped me was uninstalling gnome-terminal - after that there is no screen dimming at all, which was what I wanted to achieve.

Once more, thank you all for responses, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Open dconf editor, there are several places to look. For me the setting I needed to change was found at `org/gnome/session` and was called `idle-delay`. Hope this helps :)